# How to deal with sh: 1: next: Exec format error?

Tags: nodejs, zsh, npm

I want to use npm to run a NextJS project on my Ubuntu 22.04 but every command gives me "sh: 1: next: Exec format error". Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I actually just managed to fix this - just removed node_modeles and run `npm install` again. Worked for me.